# Under what circumstances did Urmila die?

Tags: ramayana, history, lakshmana

In Ramayana, where it is mentioned under what circumstances did **Urmila - Wife of Lakshmana** die ? Because I googled and couldn't find a valid answer to it. We know that she also opposed her own husband for supporting Rama and for taking Sita to forest.

Comment: the second part of this post `Is she the most underrated mythological character in Ramayana` is really opinion-based. People may claim same about the wives  of Bharata/Shtrughana/Sugriv and so on...Hard to answer those, IMHO.

Comment: I agree about the under-rated character.. Anasuya (wife of Atri), a great pativrata, calls Sita a pativrata. Sita, in turn calls Urmila a pativrata, because at least Sita could be with her husband in the forest most of the time, but Lakshmana left Urmila in the kingdom, so she was away from him for 14 years yet was fully devoted to him, sleeping on the floor etc.

Answer (score 2):

In Valmiki Ramayana, it is mentioned that no woman become widow in Rama Rajya. So I think sisters of Sita died earlier than their husbands. 
Please refer [shloka 99](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga128/yuddha_128_frame.htm)

> While Rama was ruling the kingdom, **there were no widows to lament**, nor there was no danger from wild animals, nor any fear born of diseases.

Comment: Should we take it literally?

Answer (score 1):

According to anand ramayan,  (though it is different from valmiki ramayan) after the departure of all brothers, the sisters of sita entered fire and went to heaven (I am unable to paste the link because I have the book in pdf format but if anyone wants to read can download it - https://archive.org/details/HindiBookAnandRamayan but I pasted the pic please see
[image][image]